# Required bootstrap appear in the top left corner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, summernote

When click button submit, required bootstrap appear in the top left corner.

My code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/hv96uu6v/)

**HTML**:

```
<div class="content">
    <form action="#">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input">Text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-input" id="input" required="required" value="Title"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contents">Contents</label>
            <textarea name="text" class="summernote" id="contents" required="required" title="Contents"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
    $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200,
        width: 600
    });

    $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($('.summernote').code());
    });
});
```

The image like this :

[image]

How can I make Validation With Bootstrap appear under textarea?

Thank you

Comment: Don't understand what ou want ...

Comment: My intention, how can I make  Validation With Bootstrap appear under textarea?